# How to ensure an Android app can only be run on a tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

My Android app is specifically designed for tablet, and I do not want it to run on mobile phones.

How to ensure the app can only be run on a tablet ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: This MAY filter incorrectly, you can't just do a catch all for tablets on screen size. HOWEVER, if by wanting to 'support tablets' you just want to support big screens sizes differently (rather than realising tablets usually dont have phone call support) then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Other question got linked as a duplicate, so here is the alternative answer:

Yes go into the android market publisher page.

- Make sure your app is uploaded.
- Click on your app name.
- Scroll down to where it says 'Show devices'.
- Click that and you can exlude all mobile phones from downloading your
  app.

Failing that you can set some parameters in your manifest for screen size etc, but this is less reliable.

Answer (score -3):

Set the min and target SDK version in the manifest file to 11.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11"></uses-sdk>
```

Or if editing in Eclipse, select Uses Sdk in Manifest Extras and enter them there.

Comment: That will only work until Honeycomb is released or built and run on a phone as a custom ROM.

Comment: Agree. That's why I think using SDK version (Honeycomb) could not ensure an app to be run on tablets only.

Comment: That's true, but since both of those are unknown, this is a valid way to filter right now.

Comment: This is no longer a valid way to filer. ICS / Android 4.0