# How to restrict an applicaton only for tablet

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ensure an Android app can only be run on a tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595370/how-to-ensure-an-android-app-can-only-be-run-on-a-tablet)

Hi Is there any way to restrict the application so that It can only be installed in tablet?

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: @LadaRaider, But I dont think xlarge screen attribute is the only way to detect a device type. there is samsung tablet which is android 2.2 in that SDK there is no xlarge support. xlarge is inroduced in android 2.3

Comment: But the answers at the Linked question only talk about the manifest. The screen size does not completely conclude that this device is a tablet. Below is another possibility ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes go into the android market publisher page.

- Make sure your app is uploaded.
- Click on your app name.
- Scroll down to where it says 'Show devices'.
- Click that and you can exlude all mobile phones from downloading your
  app.

Failing that you can set some parameters in your manifest for screen size etc, but this is less reliable.

Comment: Didn't know you had market option as well, only though there were the manifest option, thanks for info.