# Android application configuration for tablets and specific resolutions

Tags: android, cordova

We are developing an Android Hybrid app using Phonegap and we need allow it to be used only for tablets on a specific resolution set from 1024x768 - 1280x800 and only for Android versions 4.0 +.

Now from what I read on this link [How to ensure an Android app can only be run on a tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595370/how-to-ensure-an-android-app-can-only-be-run-on-a-tablet)

If i set this configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml the app will appear to be downloadeble from google play only for tablets.Correct me if I am wrong.

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

This would solve my problem for allowing the app to be downloaded only for tablets but how can I configure the app to be allowed to be download only by the specific mentioned resolutions?

If there is no way to do that configuration so the store will not show to app for download for other resolutions , is there any risk that the app would not be accepted in the store if for example a tablet with the resolution of 1920x1080 would download and install the app.And a message would display telling the user that the application is not usable for the current resolution it would only work for resolutions in this range: 1024x768 - 1280x800?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your app would get pulled, but that sort of restriction is discouraged. Is your app really completely non- functional on other resolutions? If it's really necessary, make sure to make it clear in the app description.  And keep in mind you'll probably get uninstallations and negative ratings.  People don't like finding out an app doesn't work on their device.

Comment: It's not a restriction if he disables downloading the app for specific devices. But you are completely right if he somehow allows people to download and run it, and THEN tell them that "sorry, device is not supported".

Comment: Setting it up so the store wouldn't even show it for unsupported devices would be better (still a restriction), but Google discourages developers from restricting apps to certain kinds of devices.  Whether you care about what Google wants is up to you of course.  And I doubt it's possible to restrict an app to only a particular set of resolutions on the play store.